# Performance Testing - TPS Slowing to a crawl despite API returning only an empty string?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

So I am having some performance issues that I'm not understanding.

I have a SpringBoot Rest API application and I am testing a GET request which makes some external service calls. It has a steady TPS no matter how many users I throw at the test. The more users I throw at it the longer the response time takes but the TPS remains steady and the app never slows to a crawl.

However to test the baseline performance I changed the API so it doesn't make any external service calls and returns only an empty string. Response time improved from 300-400ms to 30ms and TPS shot up. However it can't handle more than 10 users now for an extended period of time. **If I give it more than 10 users the performance degrades overtime to a crawl, despite such an easy GET request of returning an empty string.**

What' could be going on here? Is this normal behavior and how can I find out more info and debug this further. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the config and version of tomcat ? i guess  it's because of the  **max-connections** limit .

Answer (score 0):

> However it can't handle more than 10 users now for an extended period of time

classic [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), use an [APM tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-the-full-application-picture-with-blazemeter-and-apm-integration) or profiler tool like [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) - it should give you more information regarding the function which causes the problems.

Alternatively (or in addition to) use a static [code analysis tool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-code-analysis-tutorial) which will possibly detect not closed handles, connections, static objects, poorly designed objects which don't have [hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) or [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) functions implemented, etc.

Comment: How can it be a memory leak if returning an empty response? The controller method for the GET request is literally just:  return new ResponseObject(); and that's it